# Acionando dinamicamente combos para criação do DOM via jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma sequencia de 3 dropdowns que modificam o DOM. Um depende do outro.
Se eu seleciono o primeiro dropdown ele modifica o DOM e os demais dropdown.
O segundo dropdown modifica o terceiro da mesma forma.
A dúvida é como acionar esses dropdowns dinamicamente?
Eu consigo preencher o primeiro.

```
 $('select#initial option[value=' + data[0].initial + ']').attr({ selected : "selected"}).prop('disabled', false);;
```

Mas o evento change que iria montar o DOM do segundo dropdown não foi acionado.

Comment: Achei a resposta $("select#initial").trigger("change");

Comment: Seria legal publicar a solução como resposta, e se colocasse o link pra documentação, perfeito :)

Answer (score 1):

Amigão, tenta fazer assim, criei um select e no evento change, crio outros elementos, tudo dinâmico via DOM.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#cboEstado')
    .append('<option>São Paulo</option>')
    .append('<option>Rio de Janeiro</option>')
    .append('<option>Minas Gerais</option>');

$('#cboEstado').on('change',function(){

    //Create a new elemment dropdown
    $('<select>')
        .prop('id','cboCidade')
        .append('<option>Araraquara</option>')
        .append('<option>Campinas</option>')
        .insertAfter($('#cboEstado'));

    //Attach event change in the new elemment
    $('#cboCidade').on('change',function(){
        $('<select>')
            .prop('id','cboItems')
            .append('<option>Item 1</option>')
            .append('<option>Item 2</option>')
            .insertAfter($('#cboCidade'));
    });
});
```

});

Código exemplo no link abaixo:
http://jsfiddle.net/rboschini/th547cnf/

☜(ﾟヮﾟ☜)

Comment: Esse seu exemplo não dispara automaticamente um evento. Ou melhor, ele dispara desde que o usuário dê a primeira ação. Para disparar um evento automaticamente é necessário usar o trigger do JQUERY. A documentação está aqui http://api.jquery.com/trigger/